# Upgrade from Angular 4 to 5 gives error : Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I am trying to upgrade the angular 4 existing project from 4 to 5. when I introduce the angular 5.0.0 or higher version and the angular cli to 1.5.0, then I see the following runtime error.

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (vendor.bundle.js:108619)
    at vendor.bundle.js:123241
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (vendor.bundle.js:123224)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (vendor.bundle.js:141637)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (vendor.bundle.js:141598)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (vendor.bundle.js:141514)
    at CompilerImpl.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser-dynamic/esm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (vendor.bundle.js:162247)
    at PlatformRef.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (vendor.bundle.js:148159)
    at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:2352)
```

The error happens only with JIT and not when ng serve aot, As instructed by some github pages, I tried to fix paths in tsconfig.app.json and also use --preserve-symlinks, but nothing helped. Could anyone help me with this?

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.1",
        "@angular/animations": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.10",
        "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "5.0.0",
        "@covalent/core": "1.0.0-beta.7",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.0",
        "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "6.1.0",
        "@types/dhtmlxscheduler": "4.3.35",
        "angular-tree-component": "6.0.0",
        "angular2-datatable": "0.6.0",
        "angular2-material-datepicker": "0.5.0",
        "angularfire2": "4.0.0-rc.2",
        "awesome-bootstrap-checkbox": "1.0.0-alpha.5",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
        "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "d3": "4.9.1",
        "datamaps": "0.5.8",
        "dropzone": "4.3.0",
        "firebase": "4.3.1",
        "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
        "fullcalendar": "3.3.1",
        "jquery": "3.2.1",
        "jquery-knob": "1.2.11",
        "jquery-ui-dist": "1.12.1",
        "leaflet": "1.0.3",
        "mdi": "^1.9.33",
        "moment": "2.18.1",
        "ng-autosize": "1.1.0",
        "ng2-dnd": "^4.2.0",
        "ng2-slimscroll": "2.0.1",
        "ngx-cookie": "2.0.0",
        "papaparse": "4.3.3",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "tether": "1.4.0",
        "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
        "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
        "widgster": "0.0.3",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
        "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "2.3.4",
        "@types/core-js": "0.9.43",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
        "@types/jquery": "3.2.1",
        "@types/leaflet": "1.2.2",
        "@types/node": "6.0.60",
        "@types/papaparse": "4.1.28",
        "codelyzer": "2.1.1",
        "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.0.0",
        "karma": "1.6.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
        "protractor": "5.1.1",
        "ts-node": "3.0.2",
        "tslint": "4.5.1",
        "typescript": "2.4.2"
    }
```

my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        routing,
        BrowserModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        CookieModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        CoreModule,
        SharedModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
```

Comment: While upgrading to package.json which modules have you upgraded? I guess it would be better to take reference from angular.io sample project

Comment: @Jovi what is the `routing` import in your app.module?

Comment: Yes it is used by other modules when routing.

Comment: @Jovi so `routing` is RouterModule? not some other property

Comment: export const routing: xxx= RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {}); yes it refers to the constant in the app-routing.module.ts